# Animated Header with ScrollView is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation, react-redux, scrollview

> this is my  profile page I want scroll animation but I didn't get output

** there is two-part one is  header and body part is fully based on card view **

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  Animated,ScrollView
} from 'react-native';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {Card, Title, Paragraph } from 'react-native-paper';
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';


import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import SafeAreaView from 'react-native-safe-area-view';


import AnimatedHeader from 'C:\Users\keerthana\Desktop\mobile-client-1\src\components\AnimatedHeader.js';

const SettingsScreen=()=>{
    const offset = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;



    return (   <SafeAreaProvider>
        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }} forceInset={{ top: 'always' }}>
          <AnimatedHeader animatedValue={offset} />
          <ScrollView
            style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white' }}
            contentContainerStyle={{
              alignItems: 'center',
              paddingTop: 220,
              paddingHorizontal: 20
            }}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            scrollEventThrottle={16}
            onScroll={Animated.event(
              [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: offset } } }],
              { useNativeDriver: false }
            )}
          >
        <View style={styles.header}>
            
             
               
          <View style={styles.headerContent}>
                <Image style={styles.avatar} source={{uri: 'https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar2.png'}}/>
                <Text style={styles.name}>
                  Name
                </Text>
          </View>
        
     <View style={{ backgroundColor: "#FFF"}}>  
        <Card style={{padding:5,borderWidth: 1,borderRadius: 1,borderColor: '#adacac',marginTop:20}}>
        <Card.Title title="INFO" subtitle="username"  />
        <Card.Content>
        <Title style={{fontSize:16}}>Phone Number</Title>
        <Paragraph>0000000000000</Paragraph>
        </Card.Content>
        <Card.Content style={{borderWidth: 0, borderColor: 'transparent', elevation: 0}}>
        <Title style={{fontSize:16}}>Slogan</Title>
        <Paragraph >Testing leads to failure, and failure leads to understanding</Paragraph>
        </Card.Content>
       </Card>
       <Card style={{padding:5,borderWidth: 1,borderRadius: 1,borderColor: '#adacac',marginTop:10}}>
        <Card.Title title="Groups"   />
       </Card>

       <View style={{padding:5,borderWidth: 1,borderRadius: 1,borderColor: '#adacac',marginTop:10}}>
          //group

         <TouchableOpacity>
         <View style={{flex: 1,justifyContent: 'center',marginLeft:20}}>
         <Image
              width={450}
              containerStyle={{flex: 0.37}}
              imageProps={{resizeMode:'cover'}}
              source={{uri: 'https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar2.png'}}
             
              activeOpacity={0.7}
            />  
             </View>
             <View style={{flex: 11,flexDirection: 'column',justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                   

                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row',justifyContent: 'flex-start', marginLeft: 9  }}>
         <Text >music game</Text>
         </View></View>
         </TouchableOpacity>
         <TouchableOpacity>
         <Text>ludo game</Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>
         <TouchableOpacity>
         <Text> game</Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>
         
         

         </View>      
     </View>
    
    </View>
    </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
   
    

    );

};

export default SettingsScreen;
const styles=StyleSheet.create({
    header:{
        backgroundColor: "#e6e3e3",
      },
      headerContent:{
        padding:30,
        alignItems: 'center',
      },
      avatar: {
        width: 130,
        height: 130,
        borderRadius: 63,
        borderWidth: 4,
        borderColor: "white",
        marginBottom:10,
      },
      name:{
        fontSize:22,
        color:"#FFFFFF",
        fontWeight:'600',
      },
      profileDetail:{
        alignSelf: 'center',
        marginTop:200,
        alignItems: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        position:'absolute',
        backgroundColor: "#ffffff"
      },
      detailContent:{
        margin:10,
        alignItems: 'center'
      },
      title:{
        fontSize:20,
        color: "#00CED1"
      },
      count:{
        fontSize:18,
      },
      bodyContent: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding:30,
        marginTop:40
      },
      textInfo:{
        fontSize:18,
        marginTop:20,
        color: "#696969",
      },
      buttonContainer: {
        marginTop:10,
        height:45,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginBottom:20,
        width:250,
        borderRadius:30,
        backgroundColor: "#00CED1",
      },
      description:{
        fontSize:20,
        color: "#00CED1",
        marginTop:10,
        textAlign: 'center'
      },

     
       
    

});
```

> animation page
> ** this animation is used for profile page scroll **

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  Animated,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';
import { useSafeAreaInsets } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

const HEADER_HEIGHT = 200;

const AnimatedHeader = ({ animatedValue }) => {
  const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();

  const headerHeight = animatedValue.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, HEADER_HEIGHT + insets.top],
    outputRange: [HEADER_HEIGHT + insets.top, insets.top + 44],
    extrapolate: 'clamp'
  });

  return (
    <Animated.View
      style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        zIndex: 10,
        height: headerHeight,
        backgroundColor: 'lightblue'
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default AnimatedHeader;
```

> without using the animation part its works properly but after adding animation  I don't know why it's not working.

Comment: It seems like your code does work in iOS but not in react native web: https://snack.expo.io/@lindapaiste/disrespectful-bagel

Comment: @LindaPaiste yes